# Regex, get only first occurrence and stop

Tags: css, regex, css-animations

I'm trying to grab each individual **keyframes** declaration in a css file, and copy it, but inserting moz/ms/o to handle each browser with keyframes.

I'm using this regex:

```
(@)(-webkit-)([\s\S]*)(\}\R\}\R@)
```

To try and capture each collection (see full example at my [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/m3x8S9xcL3))

Comment: What's your question? And what language are you doing this in?

Comment: I'm using common (Java/Ruby etc) regular expression terminology to recreate chunks of CSS so I don't have to write them by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(@)(-webkit-)(.*?\R\})/m
```

The `m` modifier makes it a multi-line regexp, so `.` matches across newlines. I removed the match for `@` at the end, because then it can't match the last block in the file. And `*?` makes the match non-greedy, so it only matches one block at a time.

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/OHHYYVcHSy)

Comment: @Charlesism The OP's regular expression seems to assume very specific layout of the CSS, so I assumed he was working with a layout that he can ensure matches the expectations. Regular expressions are not good at matching balanced braces, so this is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you get is...

```
(@-webkit-[^}]*}\s*to\s*{[^}]*}\s*})
```

...which can handle unusual/mangled indention in your CSS files [decently](http://rubular.com/r/b5l8qMj91N). This is how it works:

---

1. `(` Start a capture group...
2. `@-webkit-` ...upon this phrase.
3. `[^}]*` `}` Continue until you you see a '}' character.
4. `\s*` `to` `\s*` `{` Next, the phrase ' to ', followed by '{'...
5. `[^}]*` `}` ...keep going till the next '}' character.
6. `\s*` `}` A final '}' character, possibly preceded by whitespace.
7. `)` Stop capturing.

---

It might be that there are cases where you have a false positive since [regex doesn't understand nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets).